# Installing extended offline dictation fails without error

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

I'm trying to download the offline dictation files but I only see the download window (screenshot) and after a while it disappears and the next time if I want to use dictation the same thing happens.

Is there some cache that I can try to clear so that it would download everything from scratch?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the instructions to remove a ?.plist file (it will be recreated automagically once you restart the system).

1. Press these keys simultaneously: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
2. In the dialog box that appears after step 1, copy and paste the following

> ~/Library/Preferences

1. Hit return/enter
2. You will be presented with a ton of files, but you should be able to find the

> com.apple.assistant.plist

1. Move it to the Trash and Empty your Trash
2. Open Dictation & Speech preference panel and turn off dictation
3. Restart your computer
4. Open Dictation & Speech preference panel, turn on dictation
5. Select Enhanced Dictation
6. Download should begin and install correctly

I hope this helps.

The file you are downloading is 750 meg, so it might take a while.

Comment: Same effect after this procedure. :-(